# Copy Postgres Production RDS Database to Development RDS Instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to figure out an efficient way to copy data directly from my AWS RDS Production Postgres Instance to my AWS RDS Development Instance.

Right now I do a pg_dump on my local machine of the production instance. Then do a pg_restore on my local machine to the development RDS instance.

How can I copy the data directly from the Production RDS Postgres Instance to the Development RDS Postgres Instance?

Comment: How about just cloning the entire database instance?

Comment: If you need to use dump and restore, you could at least do it from an EC2 machine in the same region so that the data doesn't need to traverse the internet (twice) but could just flow around inside the datacenter.